# Launch helper from sandboxed application

Tags: cocoa, appstore-sandbox

I have a sandboxed application. I need it to launch a helper application (from within the main application's bundle) every time it starts up. However, this fails:

```
NSError *error;
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplicationAtURL:helperURL
                               options:NSWorkspaceLaunchDefault
                               configuration:nil
                               error:&error];
```

The error is:

> The application “Helper” could not be launched because it is corrupt., NSUnderlyingError=0x10214c700 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10827.)"}

Now, the error is misleading, because the app launches fine if I disable the sandbox entitlement. Apparently this is a bug, as reported [here](http://openradar.appspot.com/10934199).

My question is: **Is there a workaround?**

I could use `SMLoginItemSetEnabled`, as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html):

> Pass `true` to start the helper application immediately and indicate that it should be started every time the user logs in. Pass `false` to terminate the helper application and indicate that it should no longer be launched when the user logs in.

But, I can't use this API without asking the user first, because of App Store Review Guideline 2.26:

> Apps that are set to auto-launch or to have other code automatically run at startup or login without user consent will be rejected

So, using this workaround would mean asking the user "Is it OK to launch a helper every time you log in? If not, you can't use this app!" Clearly, that's not ideal...

Comment: not sure if this is related to rdar://10934199 since launchApplicationAtURL fails under sandboxing even if the app it is trying to launch has already been launched manually by the user

Comment: Can you get permission to install a user launch agent that would check whether your app was running and start the helper app ?

Answer (score 2):

A viable workaround is to use `NSTask` to spawn `/usr/bin/open` and give it the helper app's path:

```
NSTask *task = [NSTask new];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/open"];
[task setArguments: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: helperPath, nil]];
[task launch];
```

This runs fine from the sandbox, and appears to be compatible with the Mac App Store Review Guidelines.

**Update:** On further examination, this technique frequently fails with the error

> The application cannot be opened because its executable is missing.

This error does not occur when I've turned off sandboxing. So there must be a better solution...

Comment: Using /usr/bin/opendiff produces the following error in console "xcrun: error: cannot be used within an App Sandbox." Even though Apple guidelines state "the system automatically permits a sandboxed app to" "Read files that are world readable, in certain directories, including the following directories:" "/usr/bin"... I guess this is not true anymore?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SMLoginItemSetEnabled. You have to ask user consent once. After all, a helper application launched for the first time with SMLoginItemSetEnabled is automatically launched every time the user logs in.

Comment: not working for me. I have an app that just sits in the menu bar and has no windows or dock presence. `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` will register the helper but the helper is not able to launch the main app. The app is sandboxed for the app store.